# Scrabble Scores with Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm a beginner here trying to work out some stream syntax for one of my projects.  I am currently having issues trying to find:

1. the average score of all the words
2. those word above average
3. those words below average

How would I map my word value into a double that I can grab the average of for all of the words and display those averages?  And how would I split the values to above and below average using the partitioningBy method? Keeping in mind that this has to be done via Streams.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

// methods within a class

public static int scrapleVal(String word) {
    Map<Character, Integer> letterValues = new HashMap<>();
    letterValues.put('a', 1);
    letterValues.put('b', 3);
    letterValues.put('c', 3);
    letterValues.put('d', 2);
    letterValues.put('e', 1);
    letterValues.put('f', 4);
    letterValues.put('g', 2);
    letterValues.put('h', 4);
    letterValues.put('i', 1);
    letterValues.put('j', 8);
    letterValues.put('k', 5);
    letterValues.put('l', 1);
    letterValues.put('m', 3);
    letterValues.put('n', 1);
    letterValues.put('o', 1);
    letterValues.put('p', 3);
    letterValues.put('q', 10);
    letterValues.put('r', 1);
    letterValues.put('s', 1);
    letterValues.put('t', 1);
    letterValues.put('u', 1);
    letterValues.put('v', 8);
    letterValues.put('w', 4);
    letterValues.put('x', 8);
    letterValues.put('y', 4);
    letterValues.put('z', 10);

    return word.toLowerCase().chars().map(e -> letterValues.get((char)e)).sum();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] words = {"Java", "program", "list", "string", "unix",
    "hours", "syntax", "error"};
    System.out.println("Top three words are: ");
    Stream.of(words).sorted((e1,e2)->scrapleVal(e2)-scrapleVal(e1)).limit(3).forEach
    (e->System.out.println(e+" : "+scrapleVal(e)));
    
    System.out.println("\nAverage value fo words is: ");
    Stream.of(words).sorted((e1,e2)->scrapleVal(e2)-scrapleVal(e1)).forEach
    (e->System.out.println(scrapleVal(e).average()));
}
```

Comment: "I need some help" isn't a question that we can answer. Please be more specific. (Also note that it would be much more effective to make your map a constant.)

Comment: I guess my questions would be how do I map my word value  into a double that I can grab the average of for all of the words?

Answer (score 1):

To find the average `scrapleValue`, one way is to find the sum of all values and divide it by the total number of words. Ofcourse, the `sum` would be similar to the operation that you've performed inside your `scrapleValue` method.

What it would though need you to make things similar would be to `mapToInt` to get an `IntStream` where you could perform a `sum` or even directly an `average`. Hence the mapping would look like :

```
System.out.println("Average scraple value of words is: ");
double averageScrapleValue = Stream.of(words)
        .mapToInt(YourClass::scrapleVal)
        .average()
        .orElse(0.0);
```

Further note, when you want to sort words with their values, just compare them using the integer value returned by your method

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(YourClass::scrapleVal))
```

and to solve for getting the values below and above average, the *hint* in the right direction would be to look for "`partioningBy`" the average calculated in the above block.